# finding the secondhighest number in a randomly generated array in java

Tags: java

Hey guys I have a homework problem that asks me to find the second highest number of a randomly generated array and to return that number. the array has to be of length 6 and so conceptually this is what i have before i run into a wall of compiler errors. can someone please help me finish it?
update: I need to reference the array and call it in the main method im trying to do so in a system.out.println statement however i dont know how to call the proper method/array.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class SecondHighest{
 public static int find2ndHighest(int[] list){
//define how long the array can be
list[] = new int[6];
    //create a for loop to fill the array.
for(int i = 0; i>=list.length; i++){
  list[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);

}
  Arrays.sort(list);    //use the built-in sorting routine
  return list[1];

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing in a variable, only to overwrite it? Also, start by changing `i>=list.length` to `i<list.length`.

Comment: There's no question here.  Is the problem your compile errors? If so, at least post the compile errors.

Comment: Whenever you get a "wall of compiler errors", concentrate on the *first* one only. The rest of them are often just consequences of the first one.

Comment: What you have would work, once fixed for compile errors, but would be rather slow. Better would be to run through the list once, finding and remembering the largest two values in the array.

Comment: the compiler error that i get is that list[] = new int[6]; is not a statement according to the compiler.

Comment: I need to reference the array and call it in the main method im trying to do so in a system.out.println statement however i dont know how to call the proper method/array.

Answer (score 0):

your **loop** would never work as `i` would never be **greater than or equal** to **list.length**

change

```
for(int i = 0; i>=list.length; i++){
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
```

it should be **less than** because, **Array indexes start from zero and end at Arraylength-1**.

also change

```
list[] = new int[6];// this is wrong 

 to 

list = new int[6]; // you dont need sqare brackets, you only need array reference.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your compiler errors! There are many syntax errors, like calling list -> list[] after you got it as a parameter. You can just call it list! Furthermore you don't have to create a new list inside your method! Should be something like this:

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Arrays; 

    public class SecondHighest{

     public static int find2ndHighest(int[] list){

        //create a for loop to fill the array.
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
      list[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    }
      Arrays.sort(list);    //use the built-in sorting routine
      return list[1];
    }

     //define how long the array can be
      int[] list = new int[6];
      int result = find2ndHighest(list);

    }
```

I'm not sure with the Math random function..

Answer (score 0):

Also, given the fact that it is a homework problem, it would be better to not sort the entire array, since you would get O(n*logn) complexity, but iterate over the values and just keep the biggest two, for a O(n) complexity.